# GIT CI/CD failure with Python3.11

Tags: linux, git, python3

I'm running into an interesting situation. I have a machine that I'm doing some development on in *RUST* primarily, but there are a few scripts that we are doing in *Python*. For different purposes, but for the same project. There are multiple developers, and we are running everything through *GIT*, utilizing the *CI/CD* pipeline for testing, formatting, etc. We recently installed *python3.11* on the system and changed it so that *python3* pointed at 3.11.

Now when we run the *CI/CD* it fails.

[image: CI/CD Failure]

When I point it back at 3.8, no issues run just fine. Looking at the error itself, I see that it can't import the *html5lib* package.

I do some basic troubleshooting. First I create a *venv* and test with a *pip* install of *html5lib* and find that it's already installed. I can import *html5lib* at the beginning of the script with no issues. I exit the *venv*, and run a quick *python3* script using the global python to verify, and in fact, *html5lib* has no issues being imported.

Yesterday, when I was attempting all of this it was worse. *Pip* itself was failing. When I first came across the issue, I tried to install *html5lib* by using *pip*. But the install failed because, you guessed it, that it could not import *html5lib*. I attempted to make sure I had the latest version of pip by running the *pip install --upgrade pip* command, it also failed and told me the same thing, that it could not import 'html5lib'.

I did some googlefu and found several suggestions that said to make sure I had the latest pip and to use *curl* to install it. I could never get the download to even start, using this command *curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.11*.

Eventually, I can't remember how I got *pip* fixed, but I was able to install *html5lib*. However, when I reran the *CI/CD* pipeline I still got the same cannot import *html5lib* error. So for shits and giggles, I logged in as a super user and ran the *python* script with an import for *html5lib* and it failed, yes you guessed it because it couldn't import *html5lib*. At this point, I gave up and went home.

My guess is that there was something broken within the python3.11 installation and that the user running the pipeline was hitting this issue.

This morning, I pointed *python3* back to *python3.8*, and purged 3.11 from the system. Reverified the installation process, using *deadsnakes* repo, and installed *python3.11*. Everything works just fine regarding pip, *html5lib* is present. Ok, I reran the pipeline and yes again, could not import *html5lib*.

I logged back in as *super user* ran the script with the import for *html5lib*, and got a new error.

[image: super user error]

I figured, before I got down this rabbit hole, I would reach out and see if anyone else has seen anything like this and/or have some suggestions as to what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Have the script print its environment folder, then separately import that environment virtually yourself, and verify the required modules do in fact exist

Comment: @Ramhound I apologize, I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Are you speaking of the environment variables, os.environ?